# Can user choose membership start date in contribution form?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

I'm using a contribution form, where user will pay by choosing price set option with different membership period. Example:

- Price A (Membership X, 3 months)
- Price B (Membership X, 6 months)
- Price C (Membership Y, 3 months)

Currently the membership date is a rolling period, where membership start date will follow the payment date.

Is it possible to let user enter their membership start date?

For example:

- Payment date: 1st Jan
- Start date field entered in form: 3rd Jan
- After payment: Membership period starts from 3rd Jan

Is there any way to do this?